# Create an Outlook reminder every two hours

Tags: vba, outlook, reminders

I'm adding an Outlook reminder to run some code. I'd like it to run every two hours.

Below is a sample of one I have that runs every day at the same time.  So today, when the Outlook reminder kicks off, it runs some code and then creates a new reminder for two hours from when this one ran.

For example, if this one runs at 7:30 AM, I'd like the new reminder to be created for 9:30 AM and then 11:30 AM, etc.

I'm struggling with the syntax on creating the next reminder. Part of my confusion is when the date changes.

```
Case "Move Files"

Move_FILES

Call New_Task("Move ENGIE Files", DateAdd("d", 1, Date), " 7:30:00 AM")

vAuto = True
```

I've used this code for a number of different processes and it has worked for a number of years.  The only difference is now it needs to run every two hours.

```
Sub New_Task(vSubject As String, vDueDate As Date, vTime As String)

    Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem
    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

    With myItem

        .Subject = vSubject
        .DueDate = vDueDate
        .ReminderTime = vDueDate & vTime
        .Save
        DoEvents
        .ReminderSet = True
        .Save
        DoEvents
        .ReminderSet = True
        DoEvents
        .Save
        DoEvents
        .Close (olSave)
        DoEvents

    End With

    Set myItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by adding a few lines at the beginning of the CASE statement.  I added 2 variables and use them to figure out the date and time for the next reminder.  Then I pass those 2 variables to the New_Task module.  In case anyone wanted to see how I resolved my issue.  Thanks...….

```
Case "Move ENGIE Files"

Dim MyTimer As String
Dim MyDate As Date

vTime = ""
MyTimer = ""
MyDate = 0
MyTimer = CDate(Now)
MyTimer = DateAdd("h", 2, MyTimer)
MyDate = Format(MyTimer, "MM/DD/YYYY")
MyTimer = Format(MyTimer, "HH:MM AM/PM")
MyTimer = " " & MyTimer

Move_Files

Call New_Task("Move ENGIE Files", MyDate, MyTimer)

vAuto = True
```